# Sum in case -Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query:

```
select Type,

sum (case when a=1 then 1 end) as A,

sum (case when a=0 then 1 end) as B
```

this will display 2 columns A,B and their totals. 
What I need is a third column that will show the sum of A and B per row.
something like:

```
Type       A         B      Total

Apple      5                  5

Orange     3         4        7

Kiwi       2         1        3

Peach                6        6
```

I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
select Type,

sum (case when a=1 then 1 end) as A,

sum (case when a=0 then 1 end) as B,

sum (A+B) as Total
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could calculate `Total` using:

```
select Type,
  sum(case when a=1 then 1 end)        as A,
  sum(case when a=0 then 1 end)        as B,
  sum(case when a IN (0,1) then 1 end) as Total
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested only in 0 and 1 values, then this is perhaps simpler:

```
select Type, sum(a) as A, sum(1 - a) as B, count(*) as Total
from t
where a in (0, 1)
group by Type;
```

Comment: I went with the case statement since I already had it that way, but I now know it can be done this way too. thank you.